# Best Way To Load Dynamic CSS and JS With Gutenberg / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm creating a block with Gutenberg and I'm looking for a practical and easy way to load CSS and JS files via Gutenberg at the frontend.

My concern is I need to enqueue multiple JS and CSS files on save (frontend) depending on the options of the block. Say if `option1` is enabled, I would like to load `js1.js` and `css1.css`, and `option2` is enabled, load `js2.js` file only and so on.

I know that I can merge the js and css files while creating the block, but then the file size grows bigger and bigger, and I don't want to make the user load unnecessary code.

What I did is parsed the content via `WP_Block_Parser`/`gutenberg_parse_blocks` inside `enqueue_block_assets` action but I didn't like this way very much even if it works.

I was going to load the CSS and JS files with javascript but I couldn't pass the plugin URL to the block JS and I'm not even sure if this is a better option.

What do you suggest for better option?

Thank you,

Comment: There are 3 files that gutenberg work with 2 of them are CSS files in which 1 is only loaded in Editor for admin and the other one is loaded for both user and admin and apart form that there is 1 JS file which only loads in Editor.

So as a whole the end user of the site will not load a lot of data it will be just CSS and as far as admin concerns the load comes with additional functionality I have notice that gutenberg is fast a lot. As per WordPress Core team gutenberg can be loaded in 11.7 seconds if there are approximately 1000 blocks on Editor and 36000 words. For me this is fast enough.

Comment: I didn't mean that Gutenberg was not fast. What I meant was, for example I have a parallax option on my block, if it's enabled I want to load my js files as well as parallax js files, otherwise I don't need to load that file on the frontend.

Comment: There is also something unuseful with Gutenberg that, even if the block is not used on that page, you would have to load the JS file on the frontend anyways, which means you are loading the unnecessary js files.

Comment: What do you mean by front end? the editor screen or the actual front end of the site?

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot the mention at the question, the question is about the frontend. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No Problem. Now if you read my first comment then it clearly mention's there that js files are only loaded in Editor not on front end.

Comment: How do you follow a path if you are developing a block that requires frontend JS files?

Comment: I will enqueue them separately as they are decoupled here and this is how it is supposed to work. The Gutenberg editor and the block files that are associated to it by `enqueue_block_editor_assets` action are only loaded on editor. There is another hook `enqueue_block_assets` which loads file on both editor and on frontend and in the last there is `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook which we commonly using now and used before for enqueuing styles and scripts. So based on the scenario I will use the hooks accordingly.

Comment: That means, the CSS file and the JS files at the frontend are loaded without checking the blocks are used or not. If the block is not used in the page, they are loading in that page anyways.

Comment: Its all depend on the hooks you used. Developer should only load assets on frontend whose block are available on editor.